# Find all integral ordered pairs $(n,k)$ such that $\left\lfloor\frac{n^2+18n+10}{2}\right\rfloor = k^2$.

Tags: number-theory, quadratics, ceiling-and-floor-functions

I had two problems that I want to solve. The first one was easy, but the second one... not so much:

> > **First Problem:**
>
> Find all values of $n$ such that$$\frac{(n+1)(n+9)+8n+1}{2} = n^2.$$

**My Attempt:**

$$(n+1)(n+9) = n^2 + 10n + 9.$$ Therefore, the problem is asking me to find all values of $n$ such that $$\begin{align} \frac{n^2 + 18n + 10}{2} &= n^2 \\ \\ \Leftrightarrow n^2 + 18n + 10 &= 2n^2 \\ \\ \Leftrightarrow 18n + 10 &= n^2 \\ \\ \Leftrightarrow -n^2 + 18n + 10 &= 0.\end{align}$$ By the Fundamental Theorem of Algebra (FTOA), I know that there must exist only two distinct solutions for $n$. Then, using the quadratic formula, I obtain that

$$\begin{align} n &=\frac{-18\pm\sqrt{18^2 - (-4\cdot 10)}}{2} \\ \\ &= \frac{18}{2}\pm\frac{\sqrt{324 + 40}}{2} \\ \\ &= 9\pm\sqrt{364}.\end{align}$$ These are the only solutions, and since $364$ is not a square number, then these solutions are also irrational.

---

> > **Second Problem:**
>
> Find all ordered pairs $(n,k)\in\mathbb{Z}^2$ such that $$\left\lfloor\frac{(n+1)(n+9)+8n+1}{2}\right\rfloor=k^2$$ for which $n\neq k$ and we denote by $\left\lfloor x\right\rfloor$ rounding $x$ to the lowest integer.

How must I approach this problem? Because we have the $\left\lfloor\ldots\right\rfloor$ function, I assume that in at least one case, $(n+1)(n+9)+8n+1$ is odd. Therefore, in at least one case, $n$ must be odd. By trial and error, it seems like there exist only three solutions: $(2, 5), (3, 6), (4, 7)$.

**My Attempt:**

Executed *Trial and Error* and expanded the numerator, but it did not help.

---

Thank you in advance.

**Edit (Another Attempt):**

If $n$ is even, then $\exists a \in\mathbb{Z}$, the set of all integers, such that $n = 2a$. Simplifying results in $2a^2 + 24a$ $+ \, 5 = k^2$. Since the quadratic is congruent to $1$ modulo $4$ (or $a$ is a quadratic residue modulo $4$), then it definitely *can* be a square.

When $k=0$ then $a=-6\pm\sqrt{536}\notin\mathbb{Z}$ so $k\neq 0$.

When $k = 1$ then $a=-6\pm\sqrt{544}\notin\mathbb{Z}$ so $k\neq 1$.

When $k=2$ then $a=-6\pm\sqrt{568}\notin\mathbb{Z}$ so $k\neq 2$.

Now I go back to trial and error....

Comment: you can get rid of the floor function by accounting for the parity of $n$

Comment: @JorgeFernández I tried that, and now it is easier to work with, but I still am doing some trial and error. How can I prove that there are *only* three such pairs $(n,k)$ though?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The floor function seems annoying so lets get rid of it, letting $n=2m$ we get:

$\frac{(2m+1)(2m+9)+16m +1}{2}=k^2$.

So $4m^2+36m+10=2k^2$ or $(2m+9)^2 = 2k^2+71$

---

letting $n=2m+1$ we get

$\frac{(2m+2)(2m+10)+16m+9-1}{2}=k^2$

So $4m^2+40m+28 = 2k^2$ or $(2m+10)^2=2k^2+72$

---

Hence the problem reduces to finding all values of $a^2-2k^2=71$ or $a^2-2k^2=72$ which can be done with Pell equations.

Comment: Thank you very much! I am familiar with Pell equations, and also matrices, so I can handle it from here. Very nice answer. Congratulations! $$(+1) \ \ \color{green}{\checkmark}$$

Comment: my pleasure, happy to be of use !

Comment: I think there's a mistake in the $n=2m+1$ case. The equation should be ${(2m+2)(2m+10)+16m+9-1\over2}=k^2$.

Comment: yeah, thanks, let me fix it

Comment: I saw the mistake as well but figured what you meant, and doing it myself, the end result was still the same anyways

Answer (score 4):

A different approach to obtaining the Pell equations:

Note that $(n+1)(n+9)+8n+1=n^2+18n+10=(n+9)^2-71$ Let's write $N=n+9$. Then

$$\begin{align}
\left\lfloor(n+1)(n+9)+8n+1\over2 \right\lfloor=k^2
&\iff\left\lfloor N^2-71\over2\right\rfloor=k^2\\
&\iff k^2\le{N^2-71\over2}\lt k^2+1\\
&\iff71\le N^2-2k^2\lt73\\
&\iff 71=N^2-2k^2\quad\text{or}\quad 72=N^2-2k^2
\end{align}$$

Note that $71=11^2-2\cdot5^2$ and $72=12^2-2\cdot6^2$, so you do get solutions for both.

Comment: Smart... Oh, and by the way, I think you made a typo with the floor function in the left hand side of the first equation, but other than that, nice. I am not particularly good with inequalities, but still a great answer! $$(+1)$$